# Mapping values from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

I am using a text analysis service (pos) which I can pass a string at it tells me whether than string contains verbs, nouns etc.

I have code:

```
var words = new pos.Lexer().lex(req.body.Text);
var tagger = new pos.Tagger();
var taggedWords =  tagger.tag(words);
```

`taggedWords` is then passed to a handlebars template and looped through and printed.

If I `console.log(taggedWords)` I see a multidimensional array eg:

```
[ 
  [ 'Interest-only', 'RB' ],
  [ 'deals', 'NNS' ],
  [ 'allow', 'VB' ],
  [ 'only', 'RB' ],
  [ 'ends', 'NNS' ],
  ...
  ...
]
```

I would like to maintain a separate array which maps the values in the above array to human-readable version:

```
[
  ['RB', 'adjective'],
  ['NNS', 'noun'],
  ['VB', 'verb'],
  ...
  ...
]
```

and then be able to rewrite so that the original array (taggedWords) looks like:

```
[ 
  [ 'Interest-only', 'adjective' ],
  [ 'deals', 'noun' ],
  [ 'allow', 'verb' ]
]
```

and then pass this new array to my template.  What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: could you post a https://jsfiddle.net/ so we can edit there more easly?

Comment: @LuisGonzalez No need for that, SO has a local code snippets editor which is much more preferable than an external site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var taggedWords = [ 
                [ 'Interest-only', 'RB' ],
                [ 'deals', 'NNS' ],
                [ 'allow', 'VB' ],
                [ 'only', 'RB' ],
                [ 'ends', 'NNS' ]
              ];
    
var dico = {
  'RB' : 'adjective',
  'NNS' : 'noun',
  'VB' : 'verb'
};
taggedWords.forEach( elt => { elt[1] = dico[elt[1]] });
console.log(taggedWords);
```

Comment: This does work, but only if the mapping is in an object. The OP has an array of arrays, so it's not an exact solution unless he's able to change how the mapping is defined.

Comment: I doubted this, but I assumed that the question was what structure to use to transform the basic array(because of the "would like" and "then be able"). Feel free to post the solution with an array of array !

Comment: Hi - I am in control of how my mapping is defined.  I've tested your approach @romph and it does indeed work - many thanks.

Comment: @romph would you mind posting the non ES6 version as well so I can better understand what's going in your solution?

Comment: `var i; for(i = 0; i < taggedWords.length; i++){ taggedWords[i][1] = dico[taggedWords[i][1]];}` taggedWords[i][1] is the second column for each line of your array ("RB, NNS ...") and dico[taggedWords[i][1]] is equivalent to dico["NNS"] and it give you "noun", then you put it into the column of the line that you used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` to create a new array with modified elements from your original. This code changes the second item in each tagged word to what is listed in the dictionary for that tag.

```js
let taggedWords = [ 
  [ 'Interest-only', 'RB' ],
  [ 'deals', 'NNS' ],
  [ 'allow', 'VB' ],
  [ 'only', 'RB' ],
  [ 'ends', 'NNS' ]
];

let dict = [
  ['RB', 'adjective'],
  ['NNS', 'noun'],
  ['VB', 'verb']
];

let result = taggedWords.map(tag => {
  tag[1] = dict.find(item => item[0] === tag[1])[1];
  return tag;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force method would involve going through all the elements in the arrays and find a match for them in another array and push them into a third array. This will require that you don't have the same tag word in an array twice; ie: 'RB', or 'NNS'. Hope this solves your problem for now. The benefits to this method as apposed to the previous answer would be that the order of items in arrays don't matter since you're comparing each element to every other element in the other array.

```
let array1 = [ 
  [ 'Interest-only', 'RB' ],
  [ 'deals', 'NNS' ],
  [ 'allow', 'VB' ],
  [ 'only', 'RB' ],
  [ 'ends', 'NNS' ]
];

let array2 = [ 
  ['RB', 'adjective'],
  ['NNS', 'noun'],
  ['VB', 'verb'],
];

let array3 = [];

array1.forEach(el => 
{
    array2.forEach(par =>
  {
    if (el[1] === par[0])
    {
        array3.push([el[0], par[1]])
    }
  })
});
console.log(array3);
```